# Geoserver and tomcat8 conflict of port numbers on cent os

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, centos

I have installed geoserver binary and tomcat8 in /opt on centos 6.6.
My problem is, I can run geoserver only when I stop the tomcat service. How do I resolve the issue and start both on booting the system.

Comment: change the port number of one or the other, or use the Geoserver.war in tomcat

Comment: tomcat is not deploying the geoserver.war. how to do so?

Comment: Read the instructions

Comment: Hi I got the issue resolved by editing the tomcat server.xml file changin the port no to 80 as shown below, previously it ws 8080. By doing this tomcat uses 80 and geoserver will use 8080, so the conflict is resolved <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: To start geoserver on boot goto /etc and vi rc.local and add the following(Geoserver installation folder with the startup.sh path) which specifies the JAVA_HOME and GEOSERVER_HOME for the boot up and save the file. This starts the geoserver on boot.

export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export GEOSERVER_HOME=/opt/geoserver/
/opt/geoserver/bin/startup.sh

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got the issue resolved by editing the tomcat server.xml file changin the port no to 80 as shown below, previously it ws 8080. By doing this tomcat uses 80 and geoserver will use 8080, so the conflict is resolved

Answer (score 1):

To start geoserver on boot goto /etc and vi rc.local and add the following(Geoserver installation folder with the startup.sh path) which specifies the JAVA_HOME and GEOSERVER_HOME for the boot up and save the file. This starts the geoserver on boot.

export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export GEOSERVER_HOME=/opt/geoserver/
/opt/geoserver/bin/startup.sh